# Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler - execute job as group

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I want to set up some jobs in our task scheduler. Problem is that we do not want to use a user as run as user but an ant-group. 
Is that possible?

I haven't found any documentation on this specific subject, some of the here say it has to be a user, others say it looks as if a group may be used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can do it, by assigning a group to the task

[Check this](http://d.pr/i/l1qP)